Is there anyway I can use the same action for differnet bones?
Suppose Bone-1 moves up 90 units and that is called Bone_Action.
I want to use Bone_action for Bone-2.  Is there an easy way to do this?  If so what are the limits of naming my bones?  Obviously the name should be similar?

you can copy-paste the keyframes from an action to another, you need a first keyframe though, otherwise the copy-paste won't work

I know how to do that, but that is a terrible way to do it.  If I have a million copies of a mesh, I'll need a million actions to match each.  Maybe Blender has some "wildcard" naming system.
